# How to personalize the message of rich:validator

Tags: richfaces

i'm traveling now a web application width jsf 2.0 and richfaces 4.0
so, please how to personalize the message of rich:validator?

Answer (score 0):

You customize the message on the annotation in the bean.

Answer (score 0):

Have you take a look at 
http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Validation.html ?

Particularly:

```
 @Pattern(regexp = "^[\\w\\-]([\\.\\w])+[\\w]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$" , message="Bad email")

   private String email = null;
```